# Retrieve rows based on two columns values

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class      AC
eval       0.6
period     0.39
eval       0.0
generator  0.0
period     0.58
period     0.0
generator  0.0
eval       0.97
generator  0.0
```

I would like to retrieve the classes where their `AC` is zero in all the rows. Based on the previous example, the class `generator` should be retrieved since its `AC` is always zero.

When I tried the following command `subset(dataset, AC == 0)`, all the classes were retrieved which I don't want.

Comment: `df[as.logical(ave(df$AC, df$Class, FUN = function(x) all(x==0))), ]
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r subset rows by criteria and by factor group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828941/r-subset-rows-by-criteria-and-by-factor-group)

Comment: Do you want just the values of `Class` that meet the criterion or the sub-dataframe of those Classes?

Comment: You're not using the function `subset()` correctly; it should be: `subset(dataset, dataset$AC == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Here are several possibilities.

Base R

```
i <- as.logical(with(dataset, ave(AC, Class, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0))))
dataset[i, ]
#      Class AC
#4 generator  0
#7 generator  0
#9 generator  0
```

Just the `Class`.

```
j <- with(dataset, tapply(AC, Class, FUN = function(x) all(x == 0)))
names(j)[j]
#[1] "generator"
```

And a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  filter(all(AC == 0))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
## Groups:   Class [1]
#  Class        AC
#  <fct>     <dbl>
#1 generator     0
#2 generator     0
#3 generator     0
```

**Data.**

```
dataset <- read.table(text = "
Class      AC
eval       0.6
period     0.39
eval       0.0
generator  0.0
period     0.58
period     0.0
generator  0.0
eval       0.97
generator  0.0                      
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using filter , select all not zero item class and using `%in%` filter again

```
dataset[!dataset$Class%in%dataset$Class[dataset$AC!=0],]
      Class AC
4 generator  0
7 generator  0
9 generator  0
```

Comment: Why negate twice? Isn't it simpler to select equal to zero? Upvote.

Comment: @RuiBarradas if select zero ,it does not mean all AC is 0 . :-)

Comment: Right, I said it without trying.